# How do I access an array within an Object having dynamic index in handlebar?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

i am trying to access the following array within a handlebars template:

```
myobj= {
    '5d842f0706f2a639183226bc': [
        {
            order_no: '5d842f0706f2a639183226bc',
            order_date: 'Sep 20, 2019',
            products: [Object],
            supplier: [Object],
            quantity: 1
        }
    ],
    '5d842e6406f2a639183226b9': [
        {
            order_no: '5d842e6406f2a639183226b9',
            order_date: 'Sep 20, 2019',
            products: [Object],
            supplier: [Object],
            quantity: 1
        }
    ]
}
```

tried

```
{{#each mail_obj }}
    {{#each @index}}
        <p> {{this.order_no}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

If the above is not possible, how would I write a helper that could access a specific item within the array?

Comment: muobj is declared as object and setting data of array ?

Comment: myobj is Array or Object ?

Comment: You are setting data of Object to Array Please provide http://codepen.io demo of you problem

Comment: @ManjuJohn, are you sure `myobj` is an array? It does not seem to have numeric keys. Could you provide the entire `myobj` data?

Comment: Sorry myobj is an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this in your .hbs file

```
  {{#each myobj as |item|}}
    {{#each item as |details|}}
      <p>{{details.order_no}}</p>
      <p>{{details.order_date}}</p>
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
```